# how to create user registration with help of liferay registration portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portal

I'm new to liferay, trying to create web app using liferay portlets. I'm trying to create a custom registration portlet with help of liferay registration API

Comment: Did you already tried something? Where are the problems? Allready had a look at documentation? http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide

Comment: please provide more information: What are you missing in the existing registration portlet that requires you to build your own? Plus, what Dan P. asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new registration portlet i suggest you to modify existing registration portlet uisng **hook** or you can add more fields into it using **custom field** facility.

Let me know if you want more info.

HTH

Comment: I have same problem I want to add some extra text field in edit_user.jsp so I create a hook and add new txt field. field is displaying as per my requirement but I haven't any knowledge where I can get this txt field value to store in my local database table. please help me . you can check my question also on stack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174537/how-can-i-get-jsp-hook-textbox-value-in-user-service-hook